# BizTalk singleton orchestration instance has been flooded

Tags: biztalk

We have a singleton (sequential convoy) orchestration instance which has been flooded with about 14000 messages. This has meant that the instance has been processing for 8 days, but the rate of processing is currently very slow (about 1 per 7 minutes). The instance started fast, but has slowed down to this current performance level over the past few days.

We have diverted further messages away from this instance and our plan is to terminate it once it has finished processing through the backlog.

The problem is, based on the current processing rate we have calculated we have three days before it finishes (about 660 messages left to process).

My question is: Is there any way we can speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to create a workaround to this:

1. Query the messagebox and retrieve all the messages which were *consumed but not processed*
2. Kill the slow-performing orchestration instance
3. Pipe all the unprocessed messages back in which created a new instance of the orchestration.

This new instance was unencumbered by all the history (consumed messages) of the previous instance, and so ran about 60 times faster, clearing the remaining backlog fast.

The way we identified *consumed-but-not-processed* messages was by using the method I documented here: [Technique for knowing the number of consumed but unprocessed messages for a given BizTalk sequential convoy orchestration instance](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=53234&type=member&item=144996328)

The rest, once you have retrieved a list of message guids from the messagebox db is documented at the following locations:

- [How to retrieve Message Body from BizTalk Database](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.biztalk.general/WZwDiAcxeAI%5B1-25%5D)
- [3 ways of programmatically extracting a message body from the BizTalk tracking database](http://connectedthoughts.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/3-ways-of-programatically-extracting-a-message-body-from-the-biztalk-tracking-database/) (I used the 3rd one)

In summary once you have the message IDs you select the imgPart column from the Parts table in the messagebox db and this gives you an binary encoded, compressed version of the message body. You then use the code from the above articles to reconstruct the message.

After this it was just a case of getting all the messages and then firing them back into biztalk via a MSMQ receive location.

Longer term we will need to address the flaws in our design which led to this problem occuring - although flooding was not expected, to have the performance of a running process collapse through the floor under heavy load is never a good place to be.

The problem we have is that for the majority of our consumer systems, source message ordering must be maintained. For this reason we have singletons everywhere, all of which are potentially exposed to this problem.

I have posted about message [re-sequencing](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Resequencer.html) strategies in BizTalk here: [Resequencing strategies for ordered delivery in BizTalk](https://sites.google.com/site/finamics/resequencing-strategies-for-ordered-delivery-in-biztalk)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Out of interest, there is a 4th way of - the SPROC ops_LoadTrackedPartFragment can be used to reassemble message fragments from MsgBoxDb or DtaDb (it is used by the BtsAdmin MMC Tracked message UI). You can speed searching through especially DtaDb tremendously by adding a SQL index to Tracking_Parts1(uidPartID), especially if the message backlog has become horrible.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @nonnb will try that next time - sounds alot less hassle

Answer (score 1):

We noticed similar behaviour with our initial singleton / multiton pattern. It seemed that the cause was because so many messages 'correlate' with the orchestration, even though a message has completed processing, it does not reliably get removed from the messagebox because the orchestration instance was still running (BTS 2009, no SP's). Once the spool table hit ~500k rows, all Hosts entered a throttling state (I think it was 6), and then the throughput slowed dramatically.

The following helped:

1. We ensured that our messages and variables were tightly scoped in the orch, causing them to go out of scope as soon as they were no longer needed.
2. We added a timeout to allow the multitons to 'die' after a period of inactivity, e.g.  60 seconds. The downside of this was that if new messages arrive as the orch is dying, that Zombies can result. Fortunately we were able to get our partners to send messages in bursts with delays in between, which has avoided this issue.

If you find that your servers are throttling due to messagebox / spool table levels, what you can do is temporarily increase the "[Message Count Threshold in database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559628%28BTS.10%29.aspx)" e.g. by a factor 10 and then restart the hosts - this might clear the current backlog.

Comment: Thanks for this - the problem appears to be as you say - consumed message count for this instance is large. I checked the spool table counter, along with all the throttling state counters but nothing is throttling and spool table is only 30K so not too large. I am now documenting a workaround procedure, will post here once we've made the change in production.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the BTS database jobs are up and running and that they have been configured properly.

Comment: Thanks yes they are all running. I have posted my workaround to this problem